# DOM to XML in JAVA is not working

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have written the following code

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();

        // Unniversity tag
        Element rootElement = doc.createElement("university");

        // Unniversity attrs
        Attr uniName = doc.createAttribute("name");
        uniName.setNodeValue(university.name);
        Attr uniLogo = doc.createAttribute("logo");
        uniLogo.setNodeValue(university.pathToLogo);
        Attr uniMission = doc.createAttribute("mission");
        uniMission.setNodeValue(university.mission);
        Attr uniVision = doc.createAttribute("vision");
        uniVision.setNodeValue(university.vision);

        rootElement.setAttributeNode(uniName);
        rootElement.setAttributeNode(uniLogo);
        rootElement.setAttributeNode(uniMission);
        rootElement.setAttributeNode(uniVision);
```

While debugging when I check the value of `doc` I found following

```
doc = (com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DocumentImpl) [#document: null]
```

What am I doing wrong? I followed [**this**](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-create-xml-file-in-java-dom/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have not set the contents of the document. You should add the following:

```
document.appendChild(rootElement);
```

To confirm that the document contains the XML structure you can print the following statement:\

```
System.out.println(document.getDocumentElement());
```

This will print [university : null]

Answer (score 0):

Well I was making a silly mistake i.e. I donot bind/add the `rootElement` with `doc`

**Updated Code:**

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

    Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();

    // Unniversity tag
    Element rootElement = doc.createElement("university");
    doc.appendChild(rootElement);                     // I forgot to add this statement
    // Unniversity attrs
    Attr uniName = doc.createAttribute("name");
    uniName.setNodeValue(university.name);
    Attr uniLogo = doc.createAttribute("logo");
    uniLogo.setNodeValue(university.pathToLogo);
    Attr uniMission = doc.createAttribute("mission");
    uniMission.setNodeValue(university.mission);
    Attr uniVision = doc.createAttribute("vision");
    uniVision.setNodeValue(university.vision);

    rootElement.setAttributeNode(uniName);
    rootElement.setAttributeNode(uniLogo);
    rootElement.setAttributeNode(uniMission);
    rootElement.setAttributeNode(uniVision);
```